# Using more than one Enum option in InputBinding.DisplayStringOptions

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to get a string of the current key bind I have like this:

```
keybind.GetBindingDisplayString(InputBinding.MaskByGroup("Keyboard"), InputBinding.DisplayStringOptions.DontUseShortDisplayNames);
```

with the parameter of DisplayStringOptions, I want to have multiple of the settings applied, specifically value 1 and value 4 of the enum. Can I do that? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`InputBinding.DisplayStringOptions`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/api/UnityEngine.InputSystem.InputBinding.DisplayStringOptions.html) is a [`[Flags]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.flagsattribute) so **YES** you can combine two of the flag values using the [Logical OR operator `|`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators#logical-or-operator-)

```
keybind.GetBindingDisplayString(InputBinding.MaskByGroup(
    "Keyboard"),
    InputBinding.DisplayStringOptions.DontUseShortDisplayNames | InputBinding.DisplayStringOptions.IgnoreBindingOverrides);
```